# How can I collect a shipping address on the checkout flow?

Tags: 8, commerce

I am using the [Commerce PayPal](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) module.  PayPal is collecting the billing address, but I need to collect the shipping address on checkout.

How can I collect the address?  Do I add an address field to the Order Entity or the Profile Entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [commerce_shipping](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping) module ;)

Just create one "free" shipping method .. or one or more regarding your needs.

Also make sure to use the shipping checkout flow for your order type!

> It's fully integrated with commerce_paypal and you even can configure
> how paypal shall treat the two addresses in regards of collection and
> updating data entered @paypal side back to your Drupal instance.